# "(unkown)" Google Contact Records I can't delete? Temporary Error (200) Numeric Code 68

Tags: contacts, sync, google

I can't delete five corrupt contact records from my Google Contacts. This is causing sync problems with my phone. Verizon, Motorola and Google all claim they can't help.

"(unkown)" Google Contact Records I can't delete? Temporary Error (200) Numeric Code 68. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't delete one particular contact in my Google Contacts and I managed to solve it with this solution. Not sure it can help you, but you can try.

1. Go to your [Google contact page](https://contacts.google.com/preview/all)
2. Press "More" and then "Export"

   [image: IMG: Press "More" and then "Export"]
3. Press "Go to Old Contacts"

   [image: IMG: Press "Go to Old Contacts"]
4. You will find old interface of Google Contacts, and there you will be able to review your "Other Contacts"

   [image: IMG: "Other Contacts"]
5. I found that all duplicates are inside "Other Contacts". Now we need to delete 18.000 duplicates :)
6. In order to quickly delete I pressed "Settings" and then selected 250 items to display per page

   [image: IMG: Settings icon]
   [image: IMG: Selection of items]
7. I used "Select All" and then "More" & "Delete". In around 15 minutes I managed to delete all duplicates (in batches of 250).

   [image: IMG: Final image]
8. Finally, I deleted all Android Contact using [this solution](http://www.droidiser.com/2013/04/delete-all-contacts-android.html) and then synced Contact to the latest Google Contact status. Finally after so long time my contacts are fixed!